# CSS Hide outer Span and show inner span

Tags: html, css

```
<span class="price">as low as <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>1,335.79</span></span>
```

Working in WooCommerce I want to hide "as low as" which is contained in an outer span yet show the price which is contained within an inner span.

If someone could guide me as to how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want them to behave like they are nested, then don't nest them.

Comment: @4castle there is some cases where you can't control how the HTML output will be like maybe this plugin

Comment: @DaniP I've made an answer that accommodates that possibility without using weird CSS to accommodate siblings.

Comment: There is no weird CSS it's just CSS, and your answer suggest wrap the text in a tag I agree that is much "cleaner"... but as I said there is some cases where you can't manage the HTML like plugins for e-commerce, OP must change the code for the plugin or insert the tag with JS.

Comment: @DaniP If I understand plugins correctly, they simply "plug in" to your existing code. It looks like the plugin related class is on a different element, so there's no issue. They should have control of the HTML, unless is WooCommerce a CMS?

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the `font-size` value to hide all text and then show the inner span text this way:

```css
.price {
  font-size: 0;
}
.price span {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<span class="price">
  as low as 
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>
     1,335.79
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Note: Will work for text, but not for, for instance, image contents.

Comment: @GolezTrol OP doesn't mention any image just the text "as low as"

Answer (score 2):

Visibility can help you here.

```css
.price {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.price > span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<span class="price">as low as 
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>1,335.79</span>
</span>
```

If removing the space taken by the hidden text is also require then the `font-size:0` is an option in *some* browsers provided you reset the inner text back to the required size.

```css
.price {
  visibility:hidden;
  font-size:0;
  }

.price > span {
  visibility:visible;
  font-size:1rem;
  }
```

```html
<span class="price">as low as 
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>1,335.79</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Note: Content will be invisible, but the space is still claimed.

Comment: That wasn't a requirement mentioned by the OP, but added.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `visibility: hidden;` on your outer `<span>`, and `visibility: visible;` on your inner `<span>`

```css
.price {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.woocommerce-Price-amount {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<span class="price">as low as <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>1,335.79</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the proper thing, and make your HTML reflect your intentions. If you want to be able to only style "as low as", then wrap that text in it's own `<span>` and hide that instead. This will be much cleaner than trying to select a text node with CSS and suffering from the CSS effecting the siblings also.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="price">
    <span class="hidden">as low as</span> 
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>
        1,335.79
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The best solution is to change the HTML, as in 4castle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37925622/1735262).

However, if for whatever reason you cannot change the HTML structure, but you *can* change the text content and the CSS, and also have a way to set the class on an object as needed (I used a hacky little piece of JS to toggle, but it could also be set during generation of a static page), you can use the [`::before` pseudoelement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to display the desired text:

```js
function handleClick(what) {
  what.classList.contains('asLowAs') ? what.classList.remove('asLowAs') : what.classList.add('asLowAs');
}
```

```css
.asLowAs::before {
  content: "as low as ";
}
```

```html
<span class="price asLowAs" onclick="handleClick(this)">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>
    1,335.79
  </span>
</span>
```