# How to hide element in a div except one?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML-code and I would like to hide the text "Cloudy, Wind : 2.4 km/h, Humidity : 100%"

```
<div class="flxvrJtnbd theDayInfos">
    Cloudy<br>
    Wind : 2.4 km/h<br>
    Humidity : 100%<br>
    <span class="dhpflXvrjt degrees coldDegrees">
        19°C                                
    </span>
</div>
```

I just need to show the degrees.

I have tried it with something like:

```
.theDayInfos:not(.degrees){
    display: none;
}
```

This did'nt work. Are there other ways do achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use font-size

```css
.flxvrJtnbd.theDayInfos {
  font-size:0rem;/*very  old browsers won't take it */
  }
.dhpflXvrjt.degrees.coldDegrees {
  font-size:1rem;/*very  old browsers won't take it */
}
```

```html
<div class="flxvrJtnbd theDayInfos">
    Cloudy<br>
    Wind : 2.4 km/h<br>
    Humidity : 100%<br>
    <span class="dhpflXvrjt degrees coldDegrees">
        19°C                                
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This works aesthetically but if someone is accessing the page with a screen reader or other accessibility device (or just copying/pasting) they will still see/select the text with `font-size: 0rem;`

Comment: @Brian yes t does, Should  it be hidden for screan readers too ? then use as well CSS dedicated to screen readers (not part of the qustion)   https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/#speaking-props-speak

Comment: whoops, you're correct.

Answer (score 3):

you can only wrap them with some element and hide this element.

Comment: indeed, it is not possible in CSS to style text-nodes; you always need a wrapper element…

Comment: not true ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925394/css-hide-outer-span-and-show-inner-span/37925472#37925472

Comment: Weird (out-of-the-box) solution, but works.. :p

Answer (score 0):

You'll want each one to be a span then hide if that span doesn't have the right class

Like this.

```css
.theDayInfos span:not(.degrees) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flxvrJtnbd theDayInfos">
  <span>Cloudy<br></span>
  <span>Wind : 2.4 km/h<br></span>
  <span>Humidity : 100%<br></span>
  <span class="dhpflXvrjt degrees coldDegrees">
        19°C                                
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text you want hidden in another element:

```
<style>
.theDayInfos *:not(.degrees){
    display: none;
}
</style> 

<div class="flxvrJtnbd theDayInfos">
    <div>
        Cloudy<br>
        Wind : 2.4 km/h<br>
        Humidity : 100%<br>
    </div>
    <span class="dhpflXvrjt degrees coldDegrees">
        19°C                                
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: span and div should not be sibbling, use one or the other to have valid HTML. `.flxvrJtnbd.theDayInfos > div {display:none;}` works too for IE8

Comment: @GCyrillus some source to support that ? span and div should not be sibbling?

Comment: Use W3C validator to find out and read the specification on the W3C (span is phrasing content that can hold and stand along phrasing content, div is not pharsing content) It is comon to most inline element but  Links (<a>) can be either use as wrapper of block element (in HTML5) or phrasing content but **not both at same time** *hope i was clear* :)